# How to update one table in MYSQL from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**Table tool**
column names:

```
id toolnumber currentduedate  
1    123      11/3/2015  
2    456      11/3/2015 
3    789      11/3/2015
```

**Table event**
column names:

```
id  eventnumber  newDuedate
7    123          11/3/2015  
9    123          11/3/2015
10   456          11/3/2015
```

What i want is when i update the newDuedate in table event it should update the currentduedate in tool table.
I am using this query:

**mysql_query**

```
UPDATE tool INNER JOIN event SET tool.currentduedate = event.newDuedate WHERE tool.toolnumber = event.eventnumber ;
```

is working fine but if i have 2 field with the same eventnumber this query update only one. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that dates in SQL adhere to a specific format

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
UPDATE tool 
INNER JOIN event on tool.toolNumber = event.eventnumber 
SET tool.currentduedate = event.newDuedate  ;
```